# Unterminated string literal in JS

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a link for the data thats present in the column in the table by using  JQuery and Ajax in Grails.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url:"${request.contextPath}/contactDataSheet/saveContacts",
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        contact_Name: $('#contact_Name').val(),
        description: $('#description').val(),
        duration: $('#duration').val(),
        followup_Required: $('#followup_Required').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function() {
        $("#tablename").append('<tr>'+'<td>'+data.contact_Name+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.description+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.duration+'</td>'+'<td>'+data.followup_Required+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<modalbox:createLink controller="followup" action="createFollowupDetails" title="Hello" width="500">'+data.followup_Required+'</modalbox:createLink>'+'<input type="button" id="popup" value="Followuprequired" onClick="method();"/>'+'</td>'+'</tr>');
        });
    }

});

});
```

I am getting the "unterminated string literal" in the above code at `append` function

Comment: unterminated means..??hw it is

Comment: this code seems syntax error free for me, are u sure its this line?

Comment: One problem I see is your URL... Javascript isn't like PHP, that won't work. You need to do `url:"$" + request.contextPath + "/contactDataSheet/saveContacts",`

Comment: The code does in fact run with no errors.

Comment: Does it work when you remove your custom tag? (`<modalbox:createLink`).
Are you loading JS with AJAX? In that case the error could be shown in the wrong file (but with the right line number)

Comment: Could be something in the data. Try serving it with apostrophes, quote marks etc converted to character entities.

Comment: @Thomas:yes it runs when i remove the <modalbox> tag .i can c the data in the column.I want to give a link to this data that i get and redirect to a a modalbox of the grails.